# how to set font-family in browser on the server in css html

Tags: html, css, font-family

I made a simple project
Inside it, I added font to all `tags`, `body` and `*`
But in `local` everything is correct and works well
Even I added `font-family` as `important`, but when the project goes to the `server`, the font is not applied

```
@font-face {
    font-family: iransans;
    src: url('./webFonts/fonts/woff2/IRANSansWeb.woff2') format('woff2');
    src: url('./webFonts/fonts/ttf/IRANSansWeb.ttf') format('ttf');
    src: url('./webFonts/fonts/eot/IRANSansWeb.eot') format('eot');
}

*,
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: iransans;
}

p,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
b,
small,
b,
span {
    font-family: iransans !important;
}
```

> `Note` : When I inspect the server, I can see the font I have applied in
> the style section, but nothing has been applied, so it is not as if I
> have given a font. That is, these codes that I put now are on the
> server, but they have no effect

A photo that confirms the correctness of the address

[image]

Warnings that can be seen in the console

[image]

Comment: Try clearing cache and check. Also better to add a fall back font. If that doesn't work check if any error is mentioned in console.

Comment: Based on your note it sounds to me like it might have something to do with the file path. Perhaps try an absolute path instead of a relative path?

Comment: Have you moved all the font files to the server?

Comment: Do you have the font installed on your system?, If yes then the problem is with the path, can you show the directory structure

Comment: @AHaworth Yes, all have been transferred correctly

Comment: In the browser console, does it tell you that it's unable to load some files?

Comment: change your path from  src: url('./webFonts/fonts/woff2/IRANSansWeb.woff2') format('woff2'); to  src: url('webFonts/fonts/woff2/IRANSansWeb.woff2') format('woff2'); ...
Its finding the fonts in wrong folder

Comment: @SahilDhir It didn't change by removing ./ and it still works on local, it's broken on server

Comment: is your style.css inside the webFonts folder? or outside?

Comment: @SahilDhir It is outside the webFont folder

Comment: Did you check what the browser console has to say yet, yes or no?

Comment: @CBroe In the console, it only warns that I put the image in question

Comment: Do you have your console set to show _all_ types of messages? A CORS issue, similar to https://github.com/zjedi/hugo-scroll/issues/17, currently seems like the most logical explanation of the issue to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your `@font-face` rule has multiple errors.
You need to add multiple font formats as a comma-separated list in the `src` property like so:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: iransans;
    src: url('./webFonts/fonts/woff2/IRANSansWeb.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('./webFonts/fonts/ttf/IRANSansWeb.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Currently your adding multiple `src` properties – only the last is applied which happens to use the deprecated  `.eot` unsupported (Internet-Explorer-only) format.

Thats why you get the error

> "Downloadable font: no supported format found ..."

We can remove this eot completely. Besides, the correct format value for truetypes is `format(truetype)` - not `ttf`.

Ensure your font files were transferred correctly (as binary files). Some bundlers like webpack may try to copy/move files in text mode.
However: In this case you would usually get a OTS-parsing error.

You can try to manually replace your font files via a ftp client (e.g filezilla). If this solves the error - you have to check your file transfer settings.